# Magento 2: Not able to import store table

Tags: magento2, database, import, stores

I have exported database. The size of database approximately 10GB. I imported the database in my local server, but Few tables like `store` & `store_group` is not installed. I imported `store_group` but I am not able to import table store. It returns error "Cannot add foreign constraints" every time.

I tried all the possible ways but I am stuck.

Could you please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue trying to import a clean and fresh install DB of magento2 via phpmyadmin, even if I disable the foreign key checks when exporting the db.

I would recommend to import the database via the console, especially if it is large (I would say 10GB is rather large).

`mysql -h YOUR_DB_HOST -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS DB_TABLE_TO_IMPORT_TO < MY_DATABASE_DUMP.sql`

Obviously replace the caps words with your own info. There is no space between -p and your password.

I would also recommend to create the mysql dump via the console:

`mysqldump -h YOUR_DB_HOST -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS DB_TABLE_TO_EXPORT > MY_DATABASE_DUMPFILE.sql`

Comment: Thank you @tecjam. I imported database by console using source db.sql command but Unfortunately store related tables are not imported. :(

Comment: How did you create the db dump? Via phpmyadmin? Try dumping by console, also. I'll add the command to my code above.

Comment: I create db via following command:
mysqldump -u user -p db | gzip > `date -I`.database.sql.gz